# Using recursion to determine if a number is a palindrome

Tags: java, recursion, numbers, palindrome

The objective here is to check if a number is palindrome or not using recursion. Today is my first day with recursion so as you can see the code doesn't seem very convincing.

I tried to use print statements to see what was going wrong. The first time I ran the program I input '101'.'pal_Q' and 'temp' had the same value(101) however the output was 'The number is not a palindrome'.

I wasn't sure what was wrong so I ran it again inputting 22, but it still did not work. Is something wrong with my if statements? What is the bug?

```
private static int pal_Q = 0;
private static int originalNumber;
private static int i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    checkPal(sc.nextInt());

    if (pal_Q == temp) {
        System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");
    }
    else if (pal_Q != originalNumber) {
        System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome");
    }
}

public static int checkPal(int n) {
    pal_Q *= 10;
    if (i == 0) {
        originalNumber = n;
        i++;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    pal_Q += n % 10;
    System.out.print("Pal_Q=" + pal_Q + ", origNum=" + originalNumber);
    System.out.println(", n=" + n + " " + (n % 10));
    return checkPal(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: Do you really have to use math for this? You could easily ditch recursion and use a `StringBuilder` instead...

Comment: I know i could. But here I'm trying to work with recursion... Trying to get a hold of the whole concept

Comment: Please study java coding styleguides. Your variable/class names are all "wrong" ... and hint: most of their names are pretty confusing. Besides: you might want to study some base concepts of java first. For example you are mixing up **static** fields ... to then create an instance of your class. That is kinda very confusing; and indicating that you really really do some more "learning" first.

Comment: Why are `pal_Q`, `temp` and `i` all declared `static` when your `checkPal` method isn't?

Comment: I see what you mean JonK that was foresight on my part. I saw that the syntax was right and never bothered. Corrected now

Comment: I agree with @Jägermeister: I suggest study the general concepts of Java first, like objects, or whether or not to use static variables, et cetera. And, of course the Java Naming Conventions. Regarding your code, you should somehow determine the length of your input and compare the first 'character' with the last one (if the input is 737, first 7 and last 7 are compared. Then discard the first digit, divide the number by 10 and let the method call itself with that number.

Comment: @MCEmperor ok I understand that i need to work on my general concepts. However my question still stands( unless i have not understood your answer) if int pal_Q and int temp are equal then why is the output still   ' The number is not a palindrome.' Can you please copy down the program and run it for yourself

Comment: Guys I have to state that I accept that there are alternative ways to find a solution to a problem; however, this  is the method i have 'currently' adopted and I believe that although most of the code is right there is something I'm missing. I wanted someone to point out what I was missing. I will accept alternate solutions but my main objective here is to find out what I'm missing

Comment: Hint for understanding why your code is not working: try it with 1010 as input. You say `pal_Q` and `temp` are equals when the function returns, are you sure?

Comment: @rahulalvares Note that you're barely using the variable `i`; you only check if its value is 0 and then increment it. Use a boolean instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pbajpai21 provided an alternative solution, but I'm answering your original question.

The final value of `pal_Q` is `7370`; you only need to divide it by 10, and then your code is correct.

```
checkPal(sc.nextInt());
if (pal_Q / 10 == temp) {
    // Is palindrome
}
else {
    // Is not a palindrome
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I appreciate your advice you recommend any tutorial that i could use for my basics? I have had a couple weeks prior training in Java but so far that's as far as I've got

Comment: @rahulalvares The Java documentation provides [a tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) where you can learn the concepts of the Java language.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn about recursion, then you can also solve the problem above by converting the number to `String`, because if we have to just check whether the number is palindrome or not, then it will be very easy to solve it by first converting the number into a `String` (or character array). See the code below, check the `isPalindrome()` method, and debug it to get the recursion working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number");
    String str = String.valueOf(sc.nextInt());
    boolean isPalin = isPalindrome(str, 0, str.length() - 1);
    if (isPalin) {
        System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome");
    }
}

private static boolean isPalindrome(String num, int i, int j) {
    if (i >= j) {
        return true;
    }
    return num.charAt(i) == num.charAt(j) && isPalindrome(num, i + 1, j - 1);
}
```

Comment: @pbajpai21: You should replace `if (i > j)` with `if (i >= j)`, because when the input is an odd number of characters, it skips comparing the middle character with itself, increasing its performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which operates numerically rather than convert to `String`.  It has a simple public front-end, and uses a private back-end to do the recursion to hide the state checking info that the user shouldn't need to see or know.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeChecker {

   public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
      return backend(number, 0, number);
   }

   private static boolean backend(int original, int reversed, int reduced) {
      if (reversed == original) return true ;
      if (reduced < 1)          return false; 
      return backend(original, reversed * 10 + reduced % 10, reduced / 10);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number");
      int number = sc.nextInt();
      if (isPalindrome(number)) {
         System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");
      } else {
         System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome");
      }
      sc.close();
   }

}
```

In other languages, you could avoid the backend by using default values for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using global scope or static variables to perform recursion is usually an indication of lack of fully grasping how recursion should work. I suggest solving a few programming problems with trees and linked lists, those data structures are suitable for practicing and understanding recursion.

One possible solution to your problem, without converting the number to a String:

```
public class NumericPalindrome {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(22)); // true
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(131)); // true
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(1)); // true
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(9987)); // false
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(1331)); // true
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(-1221)); // true
       System.out.println(isNumericPalindrome(112112)); // false
   }

   public static boolean isNumericPalindrome(int n) {
       // Define how negative numbers should be handled
       if (n < 0)
          n = Math.abs(n); // or n *= -1;

       if (n < 10)
          return true;

       return isNumericPalindrome(n, n, 0);
   }

   private static boolean isNumericPalindrome(int original, int sliced, int pow) {
       if (sliced < 10)
          return sliced == original % 10;

       return isNumericPalindrome(original, sliced / 10, pow + 1) &&
              sliced % 10 == (original / (int) Math.pow(10, pow)) % 10;
   }
}
```